# Javascript replace text with image exclude textbox input

Tags: javascript, image, input, replace, textbox

How do I get it to not replace the text on textbox inputs? It doesn't do it while typing, but if you go to edit a document or input field that contains the replaced information it will and makes it impossible to edit.

I've tried to do it but it just turns the entire script off. xD

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/E0/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/5riz5vn0b/Zero.png" title="E"/>');
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/E10/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/6wm82qo8r/ten.png" title="E"/>');
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/E20/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/4j4abq9tn/twenty.png"title="E"/>');
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/E30/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/mzyp2jprv/thirty.png"title="E"/>');
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/E40/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/j4vazz6m3/forty.png"title="E"/>');
    </script>
```

Here is an image of the problem I see on the web page:

[image: Defect observed on the web page]

Comment: Its not at all clear on what you are trying to do. I get that english probably isn't your first language (hint:  I don't think `excluside` is a real word...)  I would also not use the word `it`  It's not clear on what that pronoun refers to.  Have you tried your sample in Chrome browser, using developer tools?  I'm guessing you have errors which locks up the script.  Chrome Developer tools will tell you exactly what the errors are.  Also, you might consider using JSFiddle to show us what your issue is with sample code.

Comment: You mention textbox in the tags and in the title, yet I see no textbox anywhere in your code.  What are you trying to do?  What are you trying to show the user of your web page?

Comment: That was a typo. Fixed it. >__>

The code has no error. I need it to not effect textbox inputs. Any textbox with the text that is being replaced into an image looks like such:

http://s31.postimg.org/b21q2ebej/screenshot_37.png

I cannot figure out how to make it not effect textbox input fields without turning the entire script off in the process.

Comment: Something in your code is pasting % values into regions on your webpage.  Why don't you paste the image into the html at the same time you paste the values into the system?

Comment: The values being replaced are controlled by a user. They put in the variable, the code replaces it with an image. I need it replaced still, just not in textbox or input fields.

Comment: Now that makes total sense.  Is jQuery usage not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` with selector string `"body *"` to select all elements except `<body>`; `for` loop; exclude `<input>` elements from single `.replace()` call by filtering `INPUT` `.tagName` property at `if` condition

```html
<div>E0 E10 E20 E30 E40</div>
<input type="text" value="E40" />
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll("body *");
  var url = "http://s31.postimg.org/";
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].tagName !== "INPUT") {
      elems[i].innerHTML = elems[i].innerHTML
        .replace(/(E0)|(E10)|(E20)|(E30)|(E40)/g
        , function(match, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5) {
          if (p1) return "<img src=" + url 
            + "5riz5vn0b/Zero.png title=E/>";
          if (p2) return "<img src=" + url 
            + "6wm82qo8r/ten.png title=E/>";
          if (p3) return "<img src=" + url 
            + "4j4abq9tn/twenty.png title=E/>";
          if (p4) return "<img src=" + url 
            + "mzyp2jprv/thirty.png title=E/>";
          if (p5) return "<img src=" + url 
            + "j4vazz6m3/forty.png title=E/>";
        })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is still changing the content of input fields. It is slightly better in that it is allowing me to interact with it, but it is changing it to the html, which will make it difficult on the user end.http://s31.postimg.org/6hfjngrp7/screenshot_38.png

Comment: @ChristopherThompson _"This is still changing the content of input fields."_ Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate? `input` element value at stacksnippets does not appear to be changed, here.

Comment: Yeah, I'm playing with it in Jsfiddle and it's not messing with it at first. But what's happening is once the user hits the "Submit" button and loads that page again, it alters the input field. http://s31.postimg.org/lrfeunn7f/screenshot_39.png  <--Like So. The Jsfiddle won't allow me to create an input field that stores the info and can be seen at a later for it to be effected by the script. Maybe it would be easier to have the script to not run on specific pages.

Comment: @ChristopherThompson Posting images of `javascript` does not convey actual text of `javascript` used.  _"The Jsfiddle won't allow me to create an input field that stores the info and can be seen at a later for it to be effected by the script"_ What do you mean by "stores the info"? What is "the script"? Try using plnkr http://plnkr.co to reproduce issue. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method might be to search the document for text nodes which contain E0, E10, E20, E30, E40, skipping those which are child nodes of TEXTAREA and INPUT elements, and replace each *text node* that remains with an element containing text and images.

This should avoid a potential problem of replacing `innerHTML` of container elements which have elements inside them that need to be left unchanged. While the following code runs in IE and Firefox it has not been tested it in the full context of your application.

```
function textToImages() // within document.body
{
    var checkAny = /E0|E10|E20|E30|E40/g;
    function filter( node)
    {   checkAny.lastIndex=0;
        if(checkAny.test(node.nodeValue))
        {   switch(node.parentNode.tagName)
            {   case "INPUT":
                case "TEXTAREA":  
                    return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
            }
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        }
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
    }
    filter.acceptNode = filter; // cross browser compatability
    var scan = document.createNodeIterator(
        document.body,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        filter,
        false
    );
    var node, replaceList=[];

    document.body.normalize();
    while(node = scan.nextNode())
        replaceList.push(node);
    if( replaceList.length)
        replaceList.forEach( replaceTextNode);

    function replaceTextNode( node)
    {   var html = node.nodeValue;
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        html=html.replace(/E0/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/5riz5vn0b/Zero.png" title="E"/>');
        html=html.replace(/E10/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/6wm82qo8r/ten.png" title="E"/>');
        html=html.replace(/E20/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/4j4abq9tn/twenty.png" title="E"/>');
        html=html.replace(/E30/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/mzyp2jprv/thirty.png" title="E"/>');
        html=html.replace(/E40/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/j4vazz6m3/forty.png"title="E"/>');
        span.innerHTML = html;
        node.parentNode.replaceChild(span, node);
    }
}
```

A [NodeIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator) is used to scan text nodes in the DOM, filtering for those which contain text to be replaced which are not child nodes of TEXTAREA or INPUT elements, and create a **static** list of nodes to be processed.

I had trouble with `document.createNodeIterator`in IE which requires at least 4 parameters and requires its 3rd parameter to be a function. If you encounter problems in other browsers I would suggest writing custom DOM traversal and filtering code to avoid using `NodeIterator` altogether.

Text nodes which passed through the filter are replaced by a `SPAN` element containing zero or more text nodes and one or more image elements. The node replacement function basically uses the code posted in the question. While it should be possible to replace a single text node with one or more text and image nodes, without the use of a container, it would require additional coding to create and manipulate DOM elements.